# How to play audio file from verilog simulation?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

My objective is to have a verilog module with an input (from a DE2 board like a clock or key) that triggers an audio file to play. How can I accomplish this using Quartus and a DE2 board?

Answer (score 0):

- Just start with a blinking LED.
- As second you can try a running light.
- Lesson tree is start to make noise with your FPGA.
- And now you can start to send samples from a memory to your speaker.

Don't forget: Simulate first, synthesize second!

Comment: That is not a good answer at all. He asked how to do lesson "tree", in case you haven't noticed.